# How to best keep your mobile application running at all times

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'am working on xamarin forms(I'm beginner), and I have simple notification, it's show's up perfectly when app OnCreate and also if my app is on background but when the user clean his phone and kill the app it dosen't work anymore until the user open it again. Can anynone help me please, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend including some of your code in your question so that it's clearly understandable.

If your application is not running, there is no way to show your notification.

The work around for this, is to have your application run on start-up in the background *if the user accepts*, allowing you to do such things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm sorry that I didn't explain my issue, I'm beginner in xamarin but as you wrote there is no way to show up my notification when it's has been killed right

Comment: @BazSaraa Yes that is correct, for your application to execute code (show a notification), it must be actively running. So your real question here, is "how to best keep your mobile application running at all times".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You can try to set the `.SetOngoing(true)` for your notification, if you set it, you notification will be existed and it cannot be dismissed by the user like following code.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder#setOngoing(boolean)

```
  var notification = new Notification.Builder(this, "10111")
            .SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle("Foreground")
            .SetContentText(messageBody)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.main)
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .Build();
```

If your application in the background, but your application cannot be killed by Android system, because you have foreground notification. You can see this running gif.

[image]

Comment: If this answer is helpful, please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: Here is my demo about it : https://github.com/851265601/ForeGroundService

Comment: Sure and thank you very much I will try it right now

Answer (score 0):

Better use a foreground service when dealing with apps that need to run for a longer time.
This service tells android not to kill the app when running in background or foreground.